# C program reads ascii text file but output is ISO-8859

Tags: c, linux, file

My C program reads an ASCII file and when I write back Iam getting it in a different format ( ISO-8859 ) why is that and how can I control it ? .

sample code :

```
    fp = fopen(my_template_file_name, "r");
    if  ( fp == NULL )
        perror (" fopen \n");

    fp1 = fopen(*out_my_file, "w+");
    if  ( fp1 == NULL )
        perror (" fopen \n");

    while (!feof(fp)) {
        ch = fgetc(fp);
        if (ch == SEARCH_STRING[0]) { 
            bytes_read = fread(buf, 1, strlen (SEARCH_STRING) -1 , fp);
            if (bytes_read != bytes_to_read) {                      
                fprintf(fp1, "%s", buf);

            } else {

                if (strcmp(buf, SEARCH_STRING+1) == 0)
                    fprintf(fp1, "%s", MY_REPLACE);
                else {
                    fprintf(fp1, "%c", ch);
                    fprintf(fp1, "%s", buf);
                }
            }
            continue;
        }
        fprintf(fp1, "%c", ch);
         }
```

FYI - I tried opening and writing with rb wb but to no avail. 
As a result of this a new line at end of the file is converted to a strange charcter

```
[root@localhost ]# cat /tmp/hello_template 
hello
[root@localhost ]# cat /tmp/hello
hello
�[root@localhost ]# file /tmp/hello_template 
/tmp/hello_template: ASCII text
[root@localhost ]# file /tmp/hello
/tmp/hello: ISO-8859 text
```

when I did gdb and looked at fp there was '\n' at the end of hello_template.
If it is dependent on the locale, then this code is not portable. I dont want to change the locale temporarily until I write. Iam wondering a better way like read the encoding format of the original file, fopen the second file with that encoding/format .

Comment: This comes down to the locale set in your C library, could you send me the output of the command `locale`

Comment: @Vality sounds right but how can i say to use a particular encoding/character set when I write. I saw other posts where people have this problem and java has a way to read the encoding/charset and use the same when it writes back. HOw to do it in C ?

Comment: locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=

Comment: http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Setting-the-Locale.html the setlocale function, you want to set it to either `C` or `POSIX` to guarantee no string mangling. Yup, you have a utf8 locale, this will cause this issue in some places. Please tell me if this helps, if it does I will post as an answer so others can see in future.

Comment: ASCII is the first half (0x00-0x7f) of ISO-8859-1... Please provide samples of input and output demonstrating what you think the error is.  If the input is truly 7-bit ASCII then there should be no difference.  If there is, then something about your question is does not make sense.

Comment: Why do you think this is an encoding issue? Both are single byte character sets, and I can't see how any of the characters would get altered. Is it always the last character in the file that is "Strange"?

Comment: @Greycon My guess is that this is actually using eascii which is not standardised and so can get mangled between locales...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's got nothing to do with encoding, none of what you're doing in your code snippet is affected by `$LANG`. The real problem is:

```
while (!feof(fp)) {
    ch = fgetc(fp);
    ...
    fprintf(fp1, "%c", ch);
}
```

As you will find in quite a lot of posts here, `feof(fp)` will not become TRUE before one call of `fgetc(fp)` has returned `EOF` (-1). But you don't check for that special return value and so you call `fprintf( fp1, "%c", -1 );` before your loop terminates.

Comment: @downvoter: sorry, I have accidentially submitted the post before being ready. Please check again and tell me if you are still unhappy with it

Comment: I am not the downvoter, but just to let you know, it was discussed on meta recently to be poor practise to submit an answer before it is ready, but if it is an accident don't worry about it :)

Comment: @vality completely agreed, I don't like it too if an uncomplete post is submitted with the purpose of 'being the first'. It was just a thick thumb (thanks for the comment btw.)

Comment: @Ingo +1. That fixed one problem with your suggestion but is the file format OK since ASCII is the first half (0x00-0x7f) of ISO-8859-1 ? and hence conclude that my code is portable ?

Comment: BTW: If `ch` is `char` another problem occurs. `fgetc()` typically returns 1 of 256 different `unsigned char` or `EOF`.  These different 257 values cannot be encoded in a `char`.  Best to use `int ch;`.

Comment: I don't see any problems with all 'ASCII like' encodings, including UTF-8, where you would treat multibyte sequences as separate characters but why not ... of course the replacement strings must be ASCII (aka US-ASCII) aswell for the whole file to be regardes as ASCII

Comment: back from stop (It's getting late): `fprintf()` is OK, but maybe you want to replace it by a simpler `fputc( ch, fp );` anyway